# How to get high resolution icons to use and edit in html/css ? (like social media icons)

Tags: html, css, icons

How to find good icons like social media icons to add in a website page? without downloading them, just import the code css and paste it

I tried to google those icons but I didn't find good quality ones

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Font-Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/) when you don't want to download the icons. Alternatively, you can also use Bootstrap's own icon library, [Bootstrap Icons](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/).
However, I prefer designing my own illustrations using SVG editors like Figma.